# Cannot save list as template even when not including content - 'exceeds the list view threshold'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to save a list as a template (not including content) in SharePoint Online and I get this error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

If I *was* including content, this message would make sense, as the list is exceeding the view threshold.

However, I am *not* including content, and the list is relatively small (4 columns added to the default set of columns).

I have saved other lists, with more columns, in the same environment without problems.

How can I save this list as a template?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PnP Provisioning template command:

```
CLS $userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com" $passWord = "YourSPOPassword" $encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRNDClassic" -Credentials $cred Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "C:\Temp\PnP\SPList PnP provisioning.xml
```

For details refer to [this](https://global-sharepoint.com/pnp-powershell/create-sharepoint-online-list-using-pnp-provisioning-template/) below article

Answer (score -1):

How many items existing in the list?

The error message indicates the item count exceed the list view threshold limitation.

Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us